# Android Sqlite: Is there a way to encrypt the entire data-base?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption, android-sqlite

Is there a way to perform encryption of the entire Sqlite db in Android. I wish to decrypt the entire db file when the app is launched and encrypt it when the app goes to background or when you log out. Is there a way to implement this using Java Crypto libraries? How is the performance like?

Edit: I would be interested in using SEE ( Sqlite encryption Extension), or java crypto libraries. Sqlcipher is not an option for me. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Good question, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: Use SQLCipher for Android, please: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: I am really in need of answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

Actually, doing some research I found this: [Sql Cipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/)

The page includes a tutorial, but you can find another [good] one here too: [Android Tech](http://myownandroid.blogspot.in/2013/09/sqlcipher-in-android.html)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

[SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) has a port for Android that will probably answer your needs.

It provides 256-bit AES encryption of database files.